# Generell error in GDI+ when using bitmap.save

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+

I want to take a screenshot of a frame and safe it. I used a bitmap, but always the error "Generell error in GDI", when i want to save the bitmap, occurs.

```cs
var picture = _webcamStreaming.LastPngFrame;
Bitmap bmp;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(picture))
{
bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
}
string fileName = "screenshot.jpeg";
bmp.Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
bmp.Dispose();
```

Comment: Do you have write access right to the path you're using? BTW, if you want to use `new Bitmap()`  to generate a compatible Bitmap, you should use the form `new Bitmap([Stream], true);`, otherwise you loose ICM information (if any, you can simply evaluate the file size when saving using the two different forms). -- You tagged the question `wpf` (before editing): is this actually a WPF app? If so, why a Bitmap?

Comment: @Jimi yes i have write access right to the path and it's also a WPF app. I thought it'd be a good idea to use a bitmap in my case. I have tried to generate the Bitmap you have mentioned it, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried to save the image as PNG instead of JPEG? Also, specify the full path -- You should use a BitmapSource (supports more formats and you can used it directly in your UI), but of course a Bitmap is not *forbidden*.

Comment: Please note that there is nothing about WPF in your question. The Bitmap class is part of Winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor `Bitmap(Stream)` does not copy the contents of the stream. The stream must be kept alive for the lifetime of the bitmap (see the remarks section [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-drawing-bitmap-ctor(system-io-stream))). So to fix your issue, it should be enough to extend the `using` to cover everything until the end of the code snippet.

Comment: Are you sure about this? When this Constuctor is called, the Stream passed to `GdipCreateBitmapFromStream()` is not the original stream, it's a constructed `GPStream` object, which returns a new MemoryStream from the source Stream if the source Stream `.CanSeek()`. A MemoryStream can, so the Bitmap object is actually generated from a byte array. -- We could talk about `Image.FromFile()` or `Image.FromStream()`

Comment: @Jimi I didn't try, but the documentation states explicitly: "You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Bitmap." And I have seen a bunch of very weird errors in the Bitmap class if you don't follow the recommendations to the letter.

Comment: Yes, the Stream - when there's one - needs to be kept open. But, as mentioned, there's Stream and Stream. In this case, the internal *stream* is actually a MemoryStream, which is a copy of the original Stream (which is also, here, a MemoryStream).

Comment: @Jimi You seem to be right, but then I wonder what that remark should be about. Maybe the exact behavior is different between different .NET versions? And this wouldn't be the first time I saw outdated documentation.

Comment: The *remark* is correct, but it's a general advice. You cannot document each and every nuance of a beast as the .Net framework. Also, a lot of people, for some reason, tend to use `Image.FormFile()`, less `Image.FromStream()`, many use the `new Bitmap()` Constructors that specifies a size. Other Constructors of the Bitmap object or methods of the Image class, much less. The main target of the documentation is, e.g., those who are wondering why the Image file is locked on disk, so they can find the answer quickly. Or those who generate an Image from a Stream that is not a memory Stream.

Comment: To note that the [GPStream](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/GPStream.cs,16) mentioned before, generated from the source Stream, is a .Net thing, not a GDI+ thing. It implements [IStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-istream)